# POP UP any data from aerospike without key?

Tags: aerospike

How to POP UP first data or  any random data from aero spike without key?
I don't want to use scan as it will reduce performance.If Pop UP is not possible, can  we just fetch data and delete it ? If it is possible , can we implement this as thread safe?
.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a query (basically a scan) with `maxRecords=1` specified in the `Statement` to get just a single "random" record as a result - this should be fast (similar to `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1` or `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table` in relational databases).

If you want to improve it further you can also configure the `QueryPolicy` to:

1. `setIncludeBinData(false)` if you only care about getting the PK/Digest and not about fetching the actual bins (will reduce size of the result set and network traffic).
2. `setShortQuery(true)` this will mark the query as short query (basically recommended when the results are expected to always be smaller than 100 records), Aerospike will not track short queries and will only use a single query thread (If i'm not mistaken as opposed to 4 by default of long queries), which can lead to better performance for short queries with small result sets. I suggest you check: [Differences between a Short Query and a Long Query](https://aerospike.com/docs/server/guide/queries) and also [single-query-threads](https://aerospike.com/docs/server/reference/configuration#namespace__single-query-threads).

Regrading thread safety of fetching and deleting - what is the purpose of deleting random records? if you can it is preferred to use `truncate` but it will delete all the records within a set/namespace, not sure if it fits your use case.

You can also create a query like I suggested above to fetch lets say 50 random digests (no binData needed and marked as a short query) and then delete these records with a batch delete and if the record was already deleted by another thread just ignore the error (via Policy or via code), to avoid collisions (because its a waste of resources) you can query a range of partitions and change the range for the next batch.

Comment: We have some tokens saved in the aerospike.We are getting 100s of requests in a second from clients.We need to fetch one token from aerospike and this token should not available for other request.So we need to fetch one token and delete from aerospike.That's why we asked about thread safety. Here, we don't know keys, because tokens are inserting dynamically.Is it possible here?

Comment: You can use a 2 step mechanism:
1. Query random range of potential tokens, about 50-100 with maxRecords (setIncludeBinData to false and setShortQuery to true)
2. For each fetched digest get and delete, you can use operate() command to get and delete by a digest in the same call (you can also use a batchOperate but its not mutli-record transactional it will just run operate one by one on the server side)

Notes:
* If record was already deleted by another thread just ignore the error
* To improve collisions - you can query by a range of partitions (each query will target the next range)

Comment: Ok, Thankyou for solution. I will check and update you